# Customize touch bar on lock screen?

Tags: macos, touch-bar

On the 2016 MacBook Pro with touch bar, most Apple applications allow you to customize the touch bar. It's also possible to change the control strip in the System Preferences.

However, I can't find a way to change the touch screen buttons that are displayed on the lock screen. I would like to add the backward/forward media buttons besides the play button.

Does anybody know how (or: whether) this is possible?

Comment: Same question, did you find something?

Comment: @GonzaloSolera Not yet unfortunately, I'm afraid it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to customize it yet. Seems to be ample space to place them around the "Play" icon.